# Hibernate tries to delete rows in a non-existing table in saveOrUpdate method

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, cascade

I have the following entity classes:

ClassA, ClassB and ClassC. ClassC extends ClassB which extends ClassA.

There is another entity class named ClassWithALongName.

ClassA has a many-to-one relationship with ClassWithALongName which is defined as below:

```
public class ClassWithALongName {
   @ManyToOne
   @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
   private ClassA myClassA;

   // getter-setter of myClassA
}
```

Let's say aClassC is a ClassC instance and the following lines are run:

```
org.hibernate.Session session = (Session)getEntityManager().getDelegate();
session.saveOrUpdate(aClassC);
session.flush();
```

After this, three update statements are run for ClassA, ClassB and ClassC which is expected.

What I didn't expect is a delete statement on a table that doesn't exist as so:

```
delete from ClassA_ClassWithALongName where ClassA_id=?
```

The last statement causes an exception because the actual classes have longer names and so the temporary identifier ClassA_ClassWithALongName has actually more characters. Because Oracle db prevents tables whose names have more characters than 30, it throws an exception.

I didn't understand two things.
Why is this delete necessary when only update statements are run?
Why does hibernate create such a temporary identifier which doesn't match with a table in the database.

Thanks for any hints.

As an answer to Justas comment, the exception is:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00972: identifier is too long
```

Essex Boy's answer helped me solve the issue. The entities are very complex and someone added a list with a one-to-many association that I didn't notice. I still do not get why there is a need for a delete statement during an update but I will leave that for the moment :)

Comment: What exception do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClassA_ClassWithALongName is a join table that hibernate expects

I think you have a @OneToMany relationship somewhere.

To prevent a join table you need something like :

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="DICTIONARY_ID")
```